# ASP.Net MVC Auto Login to External site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an MVC site (ASP.Net) that I want to be able to automatically login to another site using SSO into it. The site uses Javascript to authenticate and I had a php site that just had a basic for that looks like this and it works great.

```
<form name="nechoSSO" action="https://expense.cybershift.net/NE7P022ExpenseWeb/CarouselProdne7sso.jsp" method="post" >
<input type="HIDDEN" name="userid" value="<? echo $username; ?>">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="password" value="password" >
```

I now what with MVC to do the same thing, but automatically redirect and login. How can I go about doing this?

I tried with `HttpWebRequest`, but I can't get it to redirect.

```
string formUrl = "https://expense.cybershift.net/NE7P022ExpenseWeb/CarouselProdne7sso.jsp";
string dataToPOST = "username=testUser&password=password";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
// Turn off AutoRedirection
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

// Split Form data into bytes
byte[] dataToBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToPOST);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = dataToBytes.Length;

// Write Data to Stream for posting
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(dataToBytes, 0, dataToBytes.Length);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```